# How to get the Element Locators on Canvas using TestBench

Tags: testing, canvas, vaadin7, test-bench

I had developed an application using Vaadin 7 framework also using Open Layers, now i need to test the Elements On the canvas , when i tried using Vaadin Testbench , i am getting same Element Locator value for all the clicks on the Canvas ,

```
org.vaadin.addon.vol3.OLMapElement orgvaadinaddonvol3OLMap1 = $(org.vaadin.addon.vol3.OLMapElement.class).first();
```

in the above element Locator I am getting an error at org.vaadin.addon.vol3.OLMapElement  and also the class is missing ,i searched in maven repository also.

elements of the canvas in eclipse console as output

```
com.vaadin.testbench.TestBenchElement_$$_jvst5d5_1@9707bcc9
com.vaadin.testbench.TestBenchElement_$$_jvst5d5_1@9707bcca
com.vaadin.testbench.TestBenchElement_$$_jvst5d5_1@9707bccb
com.vaadin.testbench.TestBenchElement_$$_jvst5d5_1@9707bccc
com.vaadin.testbench.TestBenchElement_$$_jvst5d5_1@9707bccd
com.vaadin.testbench.TestBenchElement_$$_jvst5d5_1@9707bcce
com.vaadin.testbench.TestBenchElement_$$_jvst5d5_1@9707bccf
```

Elemet locators on the Testbench

```
org.vaadin.addon.vol3.OLMapElement orgvaadinaddonvol3OLMap12 = $(org.vaadin.addon.vol3.OLMapElement.class).first();


org.vaadin.addon.vol3.OLMapElement orgvaadinaddonvol3OLMap13 = $(org.vaadin.addon.vol3.OLMapElement.class).first();


org.vaadin.addon.vol3.OLMapElement orgvaadinaddonvol3OLMap14 = $(org.vaadin.addon.vol3.OLMapElement.class).first();


org.vaadin.addon.vol3.OLMapElement orgvaadinaddonvol3OLMap15 = $(org.vaadin.addon.vol3.OLMapElement.class).first();


org.vaadin.addon.vol3.OLMapElement orgvaadinaddonvol3OLMap16 = $(org.vaadin.addon.vol3.OLMapElement.class).first();
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not that simple, since the [canvas is only a "drawing surface"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483780/what-is-the-html5-canvas), just like you'd draw with the pencil on a piece of paper. When you're done you won't be able to get much information about the drawing except what you see. Depending on what you want to test, perhaps you can do some actions via TestBench/Selenium, take a screenshot of the canvas and compare it with another predefined image of what you'd expect to happen. But otherwise, it's not really possible to interact with what was drawn on the canvas itself

Comment: @Morfic i tried using  TestBench  on Canvas i got the above code which is of Element locator , i am not able to find the class OLMapElement , do you have any idea ? I tried with Selenium on the canvas  and getting good results . But i want to test the canvas using Testbench only , and also i am getting the elements of the canvas as in the second part of the code . and element locators of the canvas always as in the third part of the code , any suggestions ?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand a bit better your issue: you're looking for a `org.vaadin.addon.vol3.OLMapElement.class`, just like the Vaadin provided helper elements, such as `ButtonElement` or `TextFieldElement`. These elements ([full list](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/tree/master/testbench-api/src/main/java/com/vaadin/testbench/elements)) are provided by the Vaadin team with TestBench for their counterparts in the Vaadin framework. As you can imagine, they can't provide something like that for every 3rd party add-on, so unless the add-on maintainer has something similar, you won't find it.

Comment: What you could to 'tho, is to use the [developer tools (eg `F12` or `CTRL + SHIFT + I` in chrome)](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) and inspect your canvas elements for a style or an XPath, or some unique identifier (maybe you can set an Id from the code?!) that would allow you to retrieve each element, or whatever you need.

Comment: what you mentioned is correct , i tried the above(fourth) comment and got results with selenium but of with TestBench is of no avail.i will go with selenium only , tks, Because canvas is not a core element of vaadin , so using TestBench is no use

Comment: I can give it a shot maybe we can figure out something with TestBench, but I'll need a code sample from you, a [sscce](http://sscce.org) to get me started, as I haven't used the add-on before, and I need to make sure we use the same version and have the same GUI result.

Comment: To  test you required the URL which is is an internal application , i can not provide sorry for this  and also after one hour discussion with  vaadin Team ,they mentioned they dont  have helper classes that will work on the canvas , they also suggested to go for selenium. but i can provide a similar application URL  https://vaadin.com/directory/component/openlayers-3-wrapper-for-vaadin       and the source code https://github.com/VOL3/v-ol3