# Can javascript modify a page without changing neither the css or html code?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I came across https://www.wavepaths.com/ that produces a cool animation in the background that I would like to understand

At first I tought it was just a couple gradients and a css transition but using google dev tools (ctrl+shift+j) I can see there are no changing properties, nor I can exactly locate the css responsible.

I then tried to eliminate all layers adding display:none; to each element in front of this object until only the last one that actually contains the animation remains, the  tag.

```css
font: 112.5%/1.45em georgia,serif;
color: rgba(0,0,0,.8);
font-kerning: normal;
font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures contextual;
font-feature-settings: "kern","liga","clig","calt";
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
font-family: acumin-pro,sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
line-height: 1;
font-size: 16px;
text-align: left;
font-weight: 400;
box-sizing: inherit;
display: block;
width: 716px;
height: 568px;
```

```html
<canvas style="display: block; width: 716px; height: 568px;" width="716" height="568"></canvas>
```

looks like it has no special css, there's no change to the code while the animation goes on. If right clicked the canvas che be downloaded as .png at the cuttent frame.... How can javascript make those changes without altering the code?

Comment: see: [Canvas API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the HTML5 canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483780/what-is-the-html5-canvas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using something called THREE.js. Checkout the Developer Console to see a debug log by the library. Checkout more about threejs: https://threejs.org/.